# List of Objects and Shared Events

Tags: vb.net, events

Okay so I've created a list of objects from a class like

```
   For B As Integer = 0 To 5
            clients.Add(New Client)
           AddHandler clients(B).OnMessage, AddressOf clients_OnRec
   Next
```

Then this is the event declaration

```
Public Event OnRec As EventHandler
```

This is my Event

```
Private Sub clients_OnRec(ByVal sender As Object)

'Does something

End Sub
```

My question is how can i determine which instance of the class in the list raised the event. I need to be able to do something like:

```
clients(whateveronefiredit).ExecuteMethodInClass
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) Let me try explaining what is happening

Now in the list you have 5 objects of type Client and all this 5 of them call the event handler clients_OnRec on some kind of event.

When the first client raises this event the `sender` in the event handler signature `Private Sub clients_OnRec(ByVal sender As Object)` will have the client objects reference which raised the event.

so, in order to call the method `ExecuteMethodInClass` on the object which raised the event, you would do the following:

```
Private Sub clients_OnRec(ByVal sender As Object)
    Dim c As Client = CType(sender, Client) 'Cast the sender object as Client object
    c.ExecuteMethodInClass() 'This executes the ExecuteMethodInClass on the Client object which raised this event
End Sub
```

Hope that is clear.

Cheers